# Is it possible to place any div above everything else in a web page?

Tags: html, css, z-index

I'm trying to place a div on top of all divs in a web page.

The common question to this is:

- prepend your div to the body element
- add a z-index property bigger than every other's

The problem:

- i can't move my div in the DOM tree (due to angular limitations)

After reading the following article, it seems to me to be impossible.
Is that so?

http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Any help is much appreciated

UPDATE:

Thank you guys

@user2604405 - I forgot to mention the fact that I want this div to cover all page, so I think only `position: fixed` is pertinent.

@shujatAli - I've said I can't move the div due to angular limitations.

@Explosion Pills - It is ok to move the div, as long as it covers all page.

@Flavio Paulino - `z-index` solution won't work =/ (the div is way down in the DOM tree).

@Jasper - I've tried using `position: fixed;` but it doesn't work since other divs also have z-index defined. And I can't clone the elemento to body because it's outside my AngularJS module which break my model bindings

Comment: Can you change the `position` style property on the div?

Comment: i think its possible .. append the div in body as first child,set position absolute . place it at x:0 ,y: 0 . and set height width by window.innerheight and window.innerwidth

Comment: and also give max z index ...

Comment: Since `position:absolute` and `z-index` are calculated relative to their ancestors, I think you'll need to set `position:fixed` on the element so you can apply a `z-index` to get it to render over the rest of the DOM.

Comment: Otherwise, could you clone the element and then append the clone to `body`?

Comment: I've tried using `position: fixed;` but it doesn't work since other divs also have this attribute defined. (z-index)

Comment: I can't clone the elemento to `body` because it's outside my AngularJS module which break my model bindings.

Comment: Hey guys, appending the `div` to `body` actually works. Another small mistake made me think that was breaking angular bindings.

Answer (score 2):

yes!

just add the highest z-index on this div, like:

```
z-index: 1030;
```

Comment: What about if the element is nested under positioned and z-indexed elements? `z-index` is calculated relative to the element's ancestors...

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possilbe in three ways
**Relative**

```
div
{
position:relative;
left:-20px;
}
```

relative positioning will retain the original place of the element
**Absolute**

```
div
{
position:relative;
left:-20px;
}
```

Absolute positioning will not retain the original place

```
img
{
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
z-index:-1;
}
```

The above code is overlapping elements positioning, it can be made available by setting the z-index property.

Comment: In a complex DOM with positioned and z-indexed elements (e.g. AngularJS), how does any of this place the element "on top" of the other elements?